# Available memory much lower than total while idling

Tags: linux, memory

I have a server where my `free` output looks like this:

```
root@server:~# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        903M         22G        7.7G        8.2G         22G
Swap:          975M         38M        937M
```

Now this server is completely idle, only thing running are a few services like SSH with no load at all, Load average is 0.00.
I already tried clearing the buffers using `sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, buffer went down but as you can see it still uses 8.2 G.

Why are only 22 G available when the total is 31G and only 1G is used? It also seems that the kernel really can't make more than the 22G available, because the OOM reaper kills processes that ask for more, but why?

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 server with kernel version `4.15.0-24-generic`

Comment: buff/cache + free + used = total

Comment: I know that. This doesn't explain why there is 8G buffer that seemingly can't be utilized.

Comment: Well, it's being used as a cache.  So it's "in use", just not by any process.

Comment: So how can I stop it from being used as a cache? I thought that's what the drop_caches command would do (or at least temporarily free it).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the situation was similar as described here: https://serverfault.com/questions/288319/linux-not-freeing-large-disk-cache-when-memory-demand-goes-up

In my case `lsof` showed that the postgresql query log file was 276M which looked suspicious. Also I read here that postgresql's shared buffers might have something to do with it: https://serverfault.com/questions/515125/oom-despite-available-memory-cache/856010#856010

I could just restart the postgresql service and buffers/cache went down by 7.5G. In a production environment one might check those replies in greater detail.